# Crystal Reports Duplicating Field Value when summarizing 1 field

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, summary

So this is my problem, im using this functions to calculate the amount for each kind of bill.

```
if {TB_Facturas.F_Condiciones}="Efectivo" then
Numbervar  X:=X+{@T_Total}
else
X:=X

if {TB_Facturas.F_Condiciones}="Deposito" then
Numbervar  D:=D+{@T_Total}
else
D:=D
```

and this function to reset each variable when it changes to other group

```
WhilePrintingRecords;
Global numbervar X; 
X:=0;

WhilePrintingRecords;
Global numbervar D;
D:=0;
```

In the group footer a put another field with this formula for each summary

```
{@TotalClone}
```

when there are more than one value it works perfect, but when it just have to count 1 value it duplicates the result, for example if the value is 135000 the obtained result is 270000 for no reason...

here is an image so you can see what i got as a result https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU1dY.png

Comment: Why not group by kind of bill instead and let Crystal Reports compute the group total for you in the very group footer for each kind of bill?

Comment: I was going to do that, it would be much easier, but my "boss" want it this way no matter what, so I have no options :s

Comment: Well, your boss shall know that there are limitions to technologies once in a while, and this is one. This is the proper way to make it.

Comment: That's a big problems when he dosnt wants to understand xD

Comment: Can you post some sample data and table structure so that I might build a sample report in my spare time somewhere this week?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

1. Use two different groups one for each kind of bill, and let Crystal Reports summarize it all for you in each of the group footers.
2. Use Formula Fields to summarize it up manually.

To use Formulas, you need to create a Formula field from the right-hand menu (based on standard UI layout) and in your formula you need to either sum one kind or the other.

```
shared numbervar sumOfEffectiveBills;
shared numbervar sumOfDepositBills;

if {TB_Facturas.F_Condiciones} = "Efectivo" then 
    sumOfEffectiveBills+= {@T_Total}
else if {TB_Facturas.F_Condiciones} = "Deposito" then 
    sumOfDepositBills+= {@T_Total}

stringvar groupFooterSummary = "EFECTIVO: " 
                             + totext(sumOfEffectiveBills, 2) 
                             + "    DEPOSITO: "
                             + totext(sumOfDepositBills, 2)
groupFooterSummary
```

This formula output shall be as follows:

```
EFECTIVO: 99.99    DEPOSITO: 99.99
```

I don't clearly remember how to declare a shared variable using Crystal syntax, nor am I sure that you will have no code replacement to make, as I have no Crystal Reports to test, nor data to retrieve.

Comment: Sometimes one ought to put his foot on the ground to make his point. I'm pretty glad I could help.